# Apply different mathematical function in table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have two columns - Column A and Column B and it has some values like below:-

[image]

Now, I want to apply normal arithmetic function for each row and add result in next column. But Different arithmetic operator should be apply on each row. Like

A+B for first row

A-B for second row

A*B for third row

A/B for fourth row

and so on till nth record of the row with same repetitive mathematical function.

Can someone please help me with this code in Python.
python-3.x
pandas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Please take the time to prepare a clear concise question that includes a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use:

- row.name to access the index when using apply on a row
- can use a dictionary to map indexes to a operations

**Code**

```
import operator as _operator

# Data
d = {"A":[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    "B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

# Mapping from index to mathematical operation
operator_map = {
    0: _operator.add,
    1: _operator.sub,
    2: _operator.mul,
    3: _operator.truediv,
}

# use row.name % 4 to have operators have a cycle of 4
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: operator_map[row.name % 4](*row), axis = 1)
```

**Output**

Initial df

```
    A   B
0   5   1
1   6   2
2   7   3
3   8   4
4   9   5
5   10  6
6   11  7
```

New df

```
    A   B   new
0   5   1   6.0
1   6   2   4.0
2   7   3   21.0
3   8   4   2.0
4   9   5   14.0
5   10  6   4.0
6   11  7   77.0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `DataFrame.apply` on rows with [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```py
import operator

operators = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.truediv]

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: operators[row.name](*row), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   A  B     C
0  5  1   6.0
1  6  2   4.0
2  7  3  21.0
3  8  4   2.0
```